# code for print from i-pad and which all print does it support

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing, wireless

I have two questions in my mind:

- Is there any tutorial or demo code available to print via a printer on wireless network, from iPad?
- Which all printer does the iPad support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIPrintInteractionController` is a new class, which is the central class for printing in iOS. It is only available for iOS 4.2 and later.

For More information, visit

1. [UIPrintInteractionController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [Drawing and Printing in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156)

**Tutorial and Sample Code** can be found here [Printing in iOS](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=115)

Answer (score 3):

For your questions I have the following answers

1. Is there any tutorial or demo code available to print via a printer on wireless network, from iPad?
   Yes. you will get the sample code and tutorials from Apple itself. Here are the links,

   [print-photo sample code 1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PrintPhoto/Introduction/Intro.html)

   [print-webView sample code 2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PrintWebView/Introduction/Intro.html)

   [Drawing and printing guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW1)
2. Which all printer does the iPad support?
   I will get you the link to visit,

   [Air Print compatible printer list](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101127154633AA5iD3V)

   I will keep you post my status when I get more information on this second question, now I dont get any official document describing the printer list. I will get back to you when I get one. thanks :)